# IIS Restart on Updating a Web Application

Tags: iis

I have deployed multiple Web Applications in IIS, When I am deploying a modified Dll for any of this Web Application, I need to restart the IIS to get the effect of the new dll. This impacts other Applications. All of these Applications get restarted as I have restarted IIS. Is there any way by which I can restart the specific Application, for which the modified Dll has been deployed?

Comment: You can always recycle the app pool for the specific application. This can be done from iis or with a simple command as shown here: http://forums.iis.net/t/1188362.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  [Create a different "Application Pool"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731784%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) for your app (in IIS).  Make sure your app is [assigned to the new pool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732992%28v=WS.10%29.aspx).

When your app is deployed, the app pool is automatically restarted (affecting all of the other apps in that pool).  By default, everything gets deployed to the default app pool.